# Can supporting characters remain effective during long periods off screen?

Tags: technique, plot, character-development

### My protagonist develops relationships early and gets kidnapped

In my literary fiction story spanning about a decade, new relationships develop, they join with the street gang. Old relationships fade. I need to preserve or augment the character’s impact while characters are off screen for long stretches, because they come back in to play toward the end.

The major conflict is a return to society as part of the gang.

Are periodic bumps (minor mentions) by flashback *needed* to nurture a reader’s affection, or can you abandon characters for several chapters and patch it up at the end?

**Note:** An example I know of is the character James Steerforth in *David Copperfield*, who is a role model and bonds with the protagonist in school. Steerforth goes off screen in Chapter 9, gets mentioned only twice in Ch. 10 & 12 in memories, and then vanishes until Ch. 19. He then becomes a major antagonist character and is hunted through all of Europe for eloping with Copperfield’s childhood friend who was already betrothed.

That was literary fiction 170 years ago, and it was published as a serial (essentially a soap opera). I would like to know if supporting characters in a modern literary fiction novel with modern audiences needs more maintenance.

Comment: Could you clarify your question title, please? It's a bit confusing right now. First, the usage of "bump" is unconventional. (I thought you might be asking whether, for example, introducing characters by bumping into them on the street is cliché.) And second, "how often" something is done is not really relevant to your question. It sounds like what you really want to know is something like "How can I achieve X?" or "Is it necessary to do Y?"

Comment: I think the main problem is the reader forgetting about the supporting character. However, you could just reintroduce them (for example, by having the main character explain to a third character who this old acquaintance is). Relationships that survive years without contact are not strange to most people.